# kerberos + ldap : creating user access only for selected hosts

Tags: kerberos, openldap

I am trying understand kerberos & LDAP.
Working openldap(user information) & kerberos(authentication) are already installed.

I have migrated unix user(user01) to openldap using "migrationtools".
Below user and host principles are also created using kadmin..

```
            addprinc user01
            addprinc -randkey host/host01.example.com
            addprinc -randkey host/host02.example.com
```

Let's say, I have 3 hosts:

```
            host01.example.com
            host02.example.com
            host03.example.com
```

Now, my question is: how I can make sure that "user01" can access only on host01 & host02, NOT host03 ?

Thanks,
Obaid

Comment: How do you expect to bind Unix authentication to OpenLDAP? And what kind of "Unix" are you using, by the way?

Comment: Hi, in fact, I am exploring kerberos before implementing it on Hadoop cluster. In hadoop cluster we have some edge nodes; I want to create some users which will be able to login only 2 of those edge nodes to perform some command line operations on Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Then "explore" `sssd` service and `authconfig` command. It is much easier to manage Linux auth via LDAP, then require users to manually create their Kerberos tickets with `kinit` before accessing the cluster.

Comment: Caveat: when using Microsoft Active Directory you can tell `sssd` to block all users that do not belong to a specific group, but I'm not sure you can do that with OpenLDAP. Some workaround may be necessary.

Comment: Hi Samson, thanks for your suggestions. I will explore them and update you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we can do some workaround using sssd.

We can do it by editing "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf" and using "access_provider" parameter.

Considering my environment (openldap+krb5), first I tried with below parameters file "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf":

```
[domain/default] 
access_provider = ldap 
ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=demo1,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

But, as soon as I put this parameter "access_provider = ldap" all the LDAP users failed to login.

Then I tried simple access method as below parameters in file "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf":

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = demo1,demo2
```

Simple access provider worked for me.

In above example demo1 & demo2 are groups defined only on openldap and "access_provider = simple" is working. So, it is a potential candidate as my solution. And I am using "id_provider = ldap".

I would like to hear other thoughts/solution about this, so that we can find a good solution not only for me but also for others having similar scenario.

Thanks,
Obaid